# Mysql Unions on the Same Set of Joined Tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli, union

So I apologize if this has come up before, but I couldn't find a solid answer.

I am trying to get a single column of ids from a set of 3 columns in my table joined with another table.

The select statement just to get a single column would be like this:

```
SELECT id FROM TableA JOIN TableB USING (key1, key2) WHERE someValue = X;
```

Now as I understand it I can do unions to get these like so:

```
SELECT spec_id1 AS id FROM TableA JOIN TableB USING (key1, key2) WHERE someValue1 = X
UNION
SELECT spec_id2 AS id FROM TableA JOIN TableB USING (key1, key2) WHERE someValue2 = Y
UNION
SELECT spec_id3 AS id FROM TableA JOIN TableB USING (key1, key2) WHERE someValue3 = Z
```

Is there a way to reuse the TableA JOIN TableB USING (key1, key2) so it isn't joined for each select? I also have a WHERE condition that applies to all of the selects that is not shown above. Could I possibly reuse something like:

```
FROM TableA JOIN TableB USING (key1, key2) WHERE someOtherValue = W
```

I am trying to do this in PHP using mysqli. My original instinct was to use a temp table and query that, but I'm not sure how to handle that in mysqli. If I can use the table for multiple following queries that would be doubly ideal as there is extra data in the joined tables that could be used later.

Sorry if this is naive, but I'm not really a big web developer. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I am looking into temporary tables, and it seems like that might be a good way around it. I'd still like some confirmation on whether that's a good idea or not before doing anything with it.

Comment: You could try a `CASE` statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case though I'm not quite sure how useful that will be in your situation. I see what you're trying to do but, once you combine those columns together, how are you going to tell what value came from what column?

Comment: I don't care what column it came from. To give you a more concrete example of what I'm doing the 3 columns are similar to manager id, coordinator id, and supervisor id. Each is a distinctly different role even though it may not seem like it.

I am working on sending them all a similar email that's just a general managerial type email. Regardless of their exact position they will get the same email, so despite having 3 different columns that are needed for other reasons, they all get the same email.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Yeah, I'd suggest a `CASE` statement with a combined `WHERE` clause then if you really have your heart set on executing just one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no shortcut - not without changing the tables' design. Your approach is solid and you should not worry about having 3 joins in your query.

If the 3 lists of spec_ids are known to not have any overlapping values, then you could improve performance by changing `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.

---

One possible rewriting, without changing the overall `UNION` plan, is to change joins to `EXISTS` subqueries:

```
    SELECT spec_id1 AS id 
    FROM TableA 
    WHERE EXISTS
          ( SELECT * 
            FROM TableB 
            WHERE (TableB.key1, TableB.key2) = (TableA.key1, TableA.key2)
              AND someValue1 = X
          )
UNION                --- or UNION ALL
    ...
UNION
    ...
```

---

or - if the `spec_ids` are all included in another `BaseTable` - you can have something like this which might yield a better execution plan:

```
SELECT id
FROM BaseTable
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT * AS id 
        FROM TableA 
          JOIN TableB 
            USING (key1, key2) 
        WHERE someValue1
          AND TableA.spec_id1 = BaseTable.id
      )
    OR EXISTS
       ( 
       ...
       )
    OR ...
```

Comment: If there could be overlapping values in each of the 3 lists but not between the 3 lists would it be cheaper to do SELECT DISTINCT with UNION ALL or to do SELECT with UNION (No distinct or all)?

Comment: I guess the first but the best would be to test it (with your data). And you should try to optimize the 3 subqueries separately if you can use the `UNION ALL`.

Comment: That's true :-p For some reason I always try to optimize then try. I'm not used to web development where most of the stuff can be tested instantly. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try CASE statement. You should be able to do it without the UNION

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN someValue1 = X THEN spec_id1 
        WHEN someValue2 = Y THEN spec_id2 
        WHEN someValue3 = Z THEN spec_id3 
    END
 AS id FROM TableA JOIN TableB USING (key1, key2) 
WHERE 
someValue1 = X OR someValue2 = Y OR WHERE someValue3 = Z
```